Print eclipse build log
Is there a way to see all the exact compile (javac) and package (jar) commands executed by eclipse in order to create the final war package? This should allow to create a script adopting the same template to run without ecilpse. I have tried -console, -debug with no useful result.
Context:
The goal is to replicate the eclipse build process outside of eclipse with the final goal of porting it to maven. M2E plugin was tried, what it does is merely creating a pom file but but not exporting java build path configured in eclipse.

"...with the final goal of porting it to maven." - Right-click the project folder and choose Configure > Convert to Maven Project".

ECJ is far superior to a 'classic' javac build. You could, for example, just go ahead and use the .class files created by ECJ. Usually in the {project}/bin/ folder, depending on how you configured your Eclipse Java Project. You might not see that folder in Eclipse's Package Explorer or Project Navigator views (you could mess with their filters tho...), so simply look at it in your OS's file explorer.

@howlger I tried the exact same thing but it only seem to have created the bare POM. The project contains multiple jar files referenced in the file system, they don't seem to get exported to maven configuration (ex: pom.xml). I tried going through .classpath file and generating,  sections accordingly, that was only for the kind="lib" entries, yet to find a way for the kind="con" entries. Is there a easy way to do that?

A Maven dependency can pull further dependencies, so you will probably need fewer Maven dependencies than you had JAR files before. You might start from the unresolved import statements and search for the required Maven dependencies. There is also https://search.maven.org/, e.g. to search for dependencies containing a specific class (fc:...). Just adding dependencies might not be enough when the project depends on other projects, generates code, uses annotation processing or something else. For which class or JAR are you stuck? What kind of Java project you are talking about?

No, because it's not calling them.

Surprising to get to know that, how does it compile the java sources?

The Java Development Tools contains its own Java compiler, "ECJ".

Nice to know that. Is there way to enable debug logging throughout the whole process of calling ECJ? Thank you :)

@IreshDissanayaka What debug information do you expect and in which way is it helpful for you (debug or tracing information is to track down issues of the in the compiler itself)?

@howlger I want to see the all the project specific parameters passed to the compiler (ECJ). For example: in the case of javac, we have -classpath.

@IreshDissanayaka All this information is shown in Project > Properties. This answer gives the correct answer to what you actually asked, but it seems that you are stuck in an XY problem with an X that is not a solution to Y.

@IreshDissanayaka Note that ECJ is a set of Eclipse plug-ins completely integrated in to Eclipse. It isn't called as a single command, it runs all the time you are editing Java files. It uses the project configuration information directly. There is a separate command line ECJ but that isn't what is used when you are working on files in Eclipse.
